# ASPMVC - A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an `ASP.NET MVC` application, then I have a form where the user can create a user and password.

The user was getting error with the following message:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (Password="1e.q<Tm6").
```

The user was creating the following password:

```
1e.q<Tm6
```

And I guess server rejected the string because of the `<` character.

> Is that a expected behavior? are those characters normally not allowed on passwords inputs? If those are allowed how can you keep your controller safe but allow those chars?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is the expected behavior. The reason why you are getting the error is, when a form is submitted, the asp.met mvc framework will inspect the request body to see whether it has any potentially dangerous content as HTML markup(***Think about script injection***). If it detects any dangerous content,the Request Validation module will throw an error. This is by design

You can apply [`AllowHtml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) attribute to your view model property so that the request validation framework will ignore this specific property when doing the request validation step.

```
public class LoginVM
{
   public string UserName { set;get;}

   [AllowHtml]
   public string Password { set; get; }
}
```

The below text is from the official msdn page and I think it is relevant.

> It is strongly recommended that your application explicitly check all
>   models where you disable request validation in order to prevent script
>   exploits.

Comment: Thanks a lot, do you think is a good practice to allow html in a password field? Or better it as I have it right now?

Comment: Since you are not going to display password anywhere in a view, I think it is fine to use this attribute in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Use the attribute **[ValidateInput(false)]** on the controller for the solution:

```
[HttpPost]     
[ValidateInput(false)]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Product model)
```

If it is a content of the HTML type that is sending to the server, use the method **WebUtility.HtmlEncode** to encode the string and **WebUtility.HtmlDecode** to read.

Answer (score 0):

On the server side, you can use this:

Create a hidden field in asp.net and encode it.

```
hiddenFieldMessage.Value = Uri.EscapeDataString(dangerousString);
```

Then in Javascript, create a text area and decode the encoded value.

```
<script>
    (function () {
        
        const content = document.getElementById('<%= hiddenFieldMessage.ClientID %>').value;
        // decode the content back to html
        var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textArea.innerHTML = decodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('<%= hiddenFieldMessage.ClientID %>').value);
        const content = textArea.value;  // decoded value
   })
```